# Changing the value of datatable expression column

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to set a column's value in a datatable as the sum of other two columns in a datatable.I tried expression column and is working fine . But the problem is that the value of expression column is not getting updated always.Suppose A,B are two columns in the datatable and the sum of these two columns should be shown in Column 'C'.When when the value of B is changed then the value of columns 'C' is also getting changed.But not when column 'A' is changed

```
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
 dt1.Columns.Add("A", typeof(decimal));
 dt1.Columns.Add("B", typeof(decimal));
 dt1.Columns.Add("C", typeof(decimal), "A+B");
 myGridView.Datasource = dt1;
```

Comment: Can you put some of your code here? It's hard to guess with any accuracy where you are going wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Seems as though, as i posted in my answer, you are using the expression column incorrectly, I believe it is only meant to be used on one column, not two. For two you should be using a DataColumn... "Gets or sets the expression used to filter rows, calculate the values in a column, or create an aggregate column."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an educated guess without seeing your code but it seems as though if you are using Compute then you quite possibly shouldn't use an expression column for this, rather you should use a DataColumn... Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

"If you must perform an operation on two or more columns, you should create a DataColumn, set its Expression property to an appropriate expression, and use an aggregate expression on the resulting column. In that case, given a DataColumn with the name "total", and the Expression property set to this: "Quantity * UnitPrice"

Comment: Question is updated with  sample code.Please have a look.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should go like this:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("A", typeof(decimal));
dt1.Columns.Add("B", typeof(decimal));
dt1.Columns.Add("C", typeof(decimal));
foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
            dr[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[0]) + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]);
        }
myGridView.Datasource = dt1;
```